# JVM Hang Debugging

Tags: java, jvm, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

In one of our production setups we have found that the customer was facing slowness in one of our server. Upon debugging for a bit we have found evidences which suggests the jvm itself was hang completely for 15-20 seconds(Not getting into the evidences for this post). To find the causes of jvm hang we checked the following things.

- GC - We have found the GC was normal. Memory used was way below the configured xmx and load avg in the system was also normal (around 1-2). Moreover we have found in gc log that no log was printed during that 15-20 seconds interval when jvm was found hang. Before that it was working fine and worked normally post hang.
- We figured may be the underlying node (OS/hardware) itself was hang. So we checked the normal /var/log/messages and some other OS related logs. We checked the logs of an independent agent running on the same machine and it was also working fine. This suggest that there is no problem with the hardware.
- We checked if there was some heap-dump, or core dump or any other dump which can cause the jvm to freeze. We could not find any eveidence of these files been created. Moreover because our application was already using around 20GB of RAM I think a heap dump would probably take more than a minute and won't be possible in 15-20 seconds.
- We also tried to check if there were any external requests or scripts which must be requesting for jstack or histo from process at that time, but we haven't found any. I cannot confirm this because I am not sure if jvm logs somewhere when it is requested for a jstack or histo but we haven't found any scripts running or any such files been dumped.

I am not sure what else can cause the jvm to completely hang and what all logs can I enable so that we can catch the bug next time when it happens. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

We are using amazon-coretto 8. Xmx was configured as 40GB (I know this is high but this is how it is working on 1000s of other setups as well) and the memory used by java was 15GB around the time of issue. load average was between 1-2 and gc seemed to be normal after analysing the gc logs.

Comment: Something else to check: https://www.evanjones.ca/jvm-mmap-pause.html

Comment: Run with JFR: java -XX:StartFlightRecording ... The JVM could be in a safepoint, for example, due to a call to ThreadMXBean.findDeadlockedThreads(). You will be able to see the name of the safepoint in the recording.

Comment: @boneill - Thanks for the input. I have checked our GC logs again and found out that our case is different. In our case the GC never actually took time. The real time value is also always lesser than quarter of a second.

Comment: @KireHaglin - This is a Production setup with considerable amount of load and JFR slows down the application significantly. Hence it is not possible to enable jvm profiling.  But I think I understand the point you are trying to make. Basically the safepoint cause name should tell us the operation which was running. I have done a bit of research on this and am going to enable certain flags related to GC which will dump these safepoint causes in GC log itself. I have referred to https://blanco.io/blog/jvm-safepoint-pauses/  blog. I will let you guys know If anything is found. Thanks a lot.